# error in routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

When I open http://localhost:3000/users I'm getting following routing error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"req", :controller=>"friendship", :id=>"admin@ascratech.com"}
```

How to solve this?

Inside users/index.html.erb :

```
<ul>
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
  <li>
    <%= user.full_name %>
    (<%= link_to "request friendship",
              :controller => :friendships,
              :action => :req,
              :id => user.email %>)  
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Inside `FriendshipsController`:

```
def req
    @user = User.logged_in(session)
    @friend = User.find_by_email(params[:id])
    unless @friend.nil?
      if Friendship.request(@user, @friend)
        flash[:notice] = "Friendship with #{@friend.full_name} requested"
      else
        flash[:notice] = "Friendship with #{@friend.full_name} cannot be requested"
      end
    end

    redirect_to :controller => :users, :action => :index
  end
```

Inside routes.rb:

```
resources :friendships
```

Comment: i am trying to create friendship model.when i open http://localhost:3000/users it should show all the registered users and request friendship link in front of them.on clicking requst friendship it should go to friendships controllers req action.but i am getting error on index.html.erb file of users on clicking http://localhost:3000/users

Comment: What's the point with the "feedbacks" resource ? You're using a non RESTful action (`friendships#req`), your routes.rb should define some sort of routes to handle your requests to the friendhsips controller : `get 'friendships/:id' => 'friendships#req'`.

Comment: @ jef "feedbacks" resource wrote it mistakenly..its resources :friendships.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want do:

```
resources :friendships do
  member do
    get :req
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It think...
The way this is set up, Rails will be trying to fetch the resource
/friendship/req/id
where it will expect id to tell it if you want the 1st, 3rd, or 22nd req.

But you have given it
    :id=>"admin@ascratech.com"
Rails is looking for a number, and you've given it a string.